# get strange result from scipy.signal.lsim when run twice

Tags: scipy

i run scipy.signal.lsim 10 times, it seems that the x0 only be used in the first time, why?

```html
t=np.linspace(0.0,100,100*100)
    transfun=[]
    for i in range(10):
        transfun.append(signal.lti([1],[1+i,1]))
    y=[]
    for i in range(10):
        y.append(np.sin(2*np.pi*300*t)+np.random.normal(0,1,10000)+50)
    sensor_output=[]
    for i in range(10):
        tout, yout, xout =signal.lsim(transfun[i],y[i],t,X0=[50.0])
        sensor_output.append(yout)
    fig=plt.figure()
    for i in range(10):
        plt.subplot(10,1,i+1)
        plt.plot(t,y[i])
        plt.plot(t,sensor_output[i])
    plt.show()
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lsim` takes initial *state vector* as an argument, not initial output.

Transfer functions don't really have state vectors, but under the hood `lsim` is converting the transfer function to a state-space realization (which *does* have a state vector), and using that to simulate the system.

One problem is that, for a given transfer function, there's no unique realization.  `lsim` doesn't say how it converts transfer functions to state-space realizations, but given your results I took a guess which happened to work (see below), but it's not robust.

To solve this for general transfer functions (i.e., not just first-order), you'd need to work with a specific state-space realization, and also specify more than just initial output, or the problem is under-constrained (I guess a typical approach would be to require d(y)/dt = 0, and similarly for all higher derivatives).

Below is a quick-and-dirty fix for your problem, and a sketch of how to do this for first-order state-space realizations.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal

nex = 3

t = np.linspace(0, 40, 1001)

taus = [1, 5, 10]

transfun = [signal.lti([1],[tau,1])
            for tau in taus]

u = np.tile(50, t.shape)
yinit = 49

sensor_output = [signal.lsim(tf,u,t,X0=[yinit*tau])[1]
                 for tf, tau in zip(transfun, taus)]
                           
fig=plt.figure()
for i in range(nex):
    plt.subplot(nex,1,i+1)
    plt.plot(t,u)
    plt.plot(t,sensor_output[i])
plt.savefig('img1.png')

# different SS realizations of the same TF need different x0
# to get the same initial y0

g = signal.tf2ss([1], [10, 1])

# create SS system with the same TF
k = 1.234
g2 = (g[0], k*g[1], g[2]/k, g[3])

# desired initial value
y0 = 321

#solve for initial state for the two SS systems
x0 =  y0 / g[2]
x0_2 = y0 / g2[2]
output = [signal.lsim(g,u,t,X0=x0)[1],
          signal.lsim(g2,u,t,X0=x0_2)[1]]

fig=plt.figure()
for i,out in enumerate(output):
    plt.subplot(len(output),1,i+1)
    plt.plot(t,u)
    plt.plot(t,out)
plt.savefig('img2.png')

plt.show()
```

[image: Responses for lsim of different TFs with same initial output]

[image: Responses of different SS for same TF]